# Using Entity Framework, allow null attribute not updating in model

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework in Visual Studio and am working with an existing table and corresponding model. I have changed the table to allow null values for some attributes. However, when I try to update my model, it doesn't pick up the change.

I'm going into the model designer, right clicking my model, and selecting "Update Model from Database". In the next window, I see my table in the Refresh tab, but selecting it still leaves the "Next" button below grayed out. I can only click "Finish".

Any ideas on why this is?

I'm using Entity Framework 4 (I think), MS Visual Web Developer 2010, and working with an ASP.Net 3.5 MVC 2 application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clicking Finish in this case will update the model.  Updating the model will update the storage model but not necessarily the conceptual model, especially if you are doing a refresh and the property / entity is not being added for the first time.  You might have to select the property that is nullable and under its properties set Nullable to true.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about storage vs. conceptual model?

Comment: Check out this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc982042.aspx.  Explains the structure of an edmx file.  Did you try to update the property to be Nullable manually?

Comment: I did, and that's working. It just seems like a bug to me, and I was hoping someone could explain it. I'll check out that link.

Comment: I believe its due to the fact that you are allowed to tweak your conceptual side on purpose in some purposes to not match the storage model exactly.  In this case you would not want the update from database to overwrite your customizations.

Comment: @Ishmael: This is not a bug it is feature and it is big improvement in contrast to Linq-to=sql designer. Conceptual model represents your object world - you can make changes and these changes are not affected by updating Storage model which represents your relational world. For example imagine that you model inheritance in designer. Without this feature you will have to model it again after each update from database (which is exactly what happend in Linq-to-sql).